# class NameError "" is not defined

Tags: python

```
import Databaseartış
class Datatransport(b,y):
    def __init__(self,b,y):
        k=0
        self.b=b   
        self.y=y
    def loop1(aa,bb):   
        for i in range(1,91):
            print(Databaseartış.Artış(i,m,k))
            
    def loop2():
        while True:
            if k == self.b+1:
                m +=1
            if m == y+1:
                break
            k +=1
            loop1(k,m)
            
data=Datatransport(10,10)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Arda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Database.py", line 32, in <module>
    class Datatransport(b,y):
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Why do I have this error?

Comment: Do not consider the error in loop1

Comment: Well, where were you expecting `b` and `y` to come from?  Not the ones in `__init__()` (you supply values for them when instantiating the class), but the ones in the `class` line itself - those would indicate classes to inherit from.

Comment: you are trying to subclass from an undefined class b, and an undefined class y.

Comment: I just learned the classes, I made less examples thanks for your help

Comment: There is a basic problem in your class definition. I suggest going back to whatever materials you used to learn classes. Here is a discussion of classes in the standard python tutorial https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that you are expecting the `b` and `y` in `class Datatransport(b,y):` are arguments to some kind of constructor of `Datatransport` objects. This is definitely not the case.

The parentheses part of the class definition lists the base classes that the class [inherits](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) from. This causes a `NameError` in your case because there are no classes `b` or `y`. To declare the class without any base classes (actually one, `object`) simply remove the parentheses and do:

`class Datatransport:`